# Ring of invariants for $n$-tuples of Lie algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory, reductive-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\M{M}\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}$Consider the diagonal action of $\GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ on the variety of $k$-tuples of matrices, $\M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})^k$
through conjugation.  Then it is known that the ring of invariants
$\mathbb{C}[\M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})^k]^{\GL(n,\mathbb{C})}$
is generated by the functions obtained by first evaluating a non-commutative polynomial on the tuple of matrices and then applying the trace to the resulting matrix.

So for example if $k=2$, we need to look at functions like $(A,B) \mapsto \Tr(AB)$, $(A,B) \mapsto \Tr((AB)^2 A)$, etc.  Details can be found in:

[*The invariant theory of $n \times n$ matrices*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(76)90027-X), Claudio Procesi, Advances in Mathematics, Volume 19, Issue 3, March 1976, Pages 306-381

Now assuming this, suppose we are looking for the ring of invariants of tuples as before but now for the diagonal action of a reductive group $G$ on the variety of tuples $\mathfrak{g}^k$.

Then will it be true that the ring of invariants in this situation is also generated as above by first evaluating non-commutative polynomials and then taking the trace, but now we do this on the matrices obtained by considering various representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ (or $G$), just like what happens in the case of $k=1$?

Comment: I found the repeated inline use of `\underbrace` very hard to read, so edited them to exponents (as well as adding some appropriate uses of `\DeclareMathOperator`).  I hope that this was all right.

Comment: How does the determinant (for $k = 1$) arise in the framework that you describe?

Comment: @LSpice , Thank you, looks neater now !

Comment: @LSPice, determinant? determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can expressed in terms of $\{Tr(A),\ldots,Tr(A^n)\}$. ..  for example for $2 \times 2$, it is if i am not mistaken $Tr(A)^2 - Tr(A^2)$ (off by a sign or a constant could be) ..

Comment: Ah, right, I always forget [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390990/ring-of-invariants-for-n-tuples-of-lie-algebras#comment996863_390990) (even though it was discussed in [a lovely answer to a favourite question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/2815)).  But I have a suspicion for semisimple $G$ you will be missing some invariants ….

Comment: @LSpice I thought you could recover all the invariants like that , see for example this related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25439/is-every-g-invariant-function-on-a-lie-algebra-a-trace

Comment: I've never thought of Chevalley restriction [that way](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390990/ring-of-invariants-for-n-tuples-of-lie-algebras#comment996866_390990).  That's very interesting! \\ Your link to the Procesi article does not work for me; it seems to be behind a proxy.  Since the journal link is freely available, I changed to that, which I hope is OK.

Comment: Oh sure thanks again !

Comment: Thank you for informing me about that article by C. Procesi. It partially answers my question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389680/formulas-involving-traces-of-products-of-singular-hermitian-positive-semidefinit.

Comment: @Malkoun, you are welcome ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some Lie groups you will need additional invariants.  For example, for the even orthogonals you will need the  Pfaffian in addition to the Trace.

See for example:

[*Invariant theory of special orthogonal groups*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-168/issue-2/Invariant-theory-of-special-orthogonal-groups/pjm/1102620558.full), Helmer Aslaksen, Eng-Chye Tan, Chen-bo Zhu Pacific J. Math. 168(2): 207-215 (1995).

However, you can already see this with one copy of $\mathfrak{so}(2,\mathbb{F})$ and $\mathrm{SO}(2,\mathbb{F})$ acting by conjugation. For in that case the Lie algebra is $\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\-a&0\end{array}\right)|\ a\in \mathbb{F}\right\}$ and the conjugation action is trivial.  In this case the trace is identically 0 and the Pfaffian is the only useful invariant.

In case you are interested, the Lie group version of this question was addressed by myself and Sikora here:

[*Varieties of Characters*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02164.pdf), Sean Lawton & Adam S. Sikora
Algebras and Representation Theory volume 20, pages 1133–1141(2017).

Remark 1: In the above answer, I assumed the OP wanted a *fixed* representation of $G$.  As noted in the answers to this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25439/12218), if you vary over all representations, then for $k=1$ the answer is yes.  But for $k\geq 2$ the answer appears to me to still be no.  See Theorem 1 in Sikora's paper [*SO(2n,C)-character varieties are not varieties of characters*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08279.pdf); it is not exactly the same thing, but it seems to imply the result (see the comments for a strategy to fill in the details).

Remark 2: As noted already by Professor Procesi, his work cited by the OP implies the answer is yes for the Lie groups $\mathrm{GL}_n$, $\mathrm{O}_n$, and $\mathrm{Sp}_{2n}$ (by restricting $k$-tuples of generic matrices to the subvariety $\mathfrak{g}^k$).  From this one can also deduce that the answer is yes for the Lie groups $\mathrm{SL}_n$ and $\mathrm{SO}_{2n+1}$.

Remark 3: As I said in the comments, I believe the work of G. Schwarz probably implies the answer is also yes for a representation of $G_2$ (he also addresses some Spin groups).  The question for the other exceptional groups is open as far as I know.  If I were to guess, I would say it is probably true for all of them except $E_6$ which has additional symmetry as in the case of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n}$ (where the answer is no as I already indicated).

Remark 4: Once one knows the answer for a given $G$, then one also knows it for finite central quotients of $G$ (which is how one goes from the orthogonal case to the special orthogonal case for odd $n$).  Also, if one knows the answer for $G$ and $H$, then one also knows it for $G\times H$.  Putting these observations together with the known cases reduces the entire problem down to the (simply connected forms of the) exceptional groups and the spin groups.

Comment: Thank you for taking interest in my question, but how are you connecting $k >2$ case with character variety ? are we considering $Hom(F_k, G)$ where $F_k$ is the free group on $k$-generators?

Comment: Yes.  You are comparing the $G$-invariants of $\mathrm{Hom}(F_k,G)\cong G^k$ versus $\mathfrak{g}^k$.  The invariant rings are "morally'' the same.

Comment: I see .. thanks .. this is nice .. if I may ask .. is it very obvious how to pass from $G$ to $\mathfrak{g}$ (or the other way) ?

Comment: There is something to do here.  First understand the simple case of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$.  In that case the invariants you care about are those of $nxn$ traceless matrices.  So there are two steps to related the two invariant rings.  Step 1: add in the traces of single generic matrices; and Step 2: quotient by $det-1$ for each generic matrix.  In general, the relationship is in one direction you take the tangent space of the identity in the $G$-character variety of $F_k$ to obtain $\mathfrak{g}^k//G$ (and invariants of the former give invariants of the latter).

Comment: To go the other way around, you need to use a "variation function" $F:G\to \mathfrak{g}$ which is conjugation invariant.  This will turn $G$-invariants of $\mathfrak{g}^k$ into $G$-invariants of $G^k$.  This is essentially "integration".  Again, a simple example is $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ which is $X\mapsto X-(tr(X)/n)I$.  In general, you take an orthogonal structure $B$ on $\mathfrak{g}\times \mathfrak{g}$ which always exists for reductive $G$ (killing form if semisimple) and solve: $B(F(A),X)=(d/dt)|_{t=0}f(AexptX)$ for any $G$-invariant $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: thanks a lot, I need to think over your suggestions before I can make any more comments ... but final question if I may, just a curiosity .. what happens for exceptional groups ? has it been studied?

Comment: Depending on what you want, there are many open questions.  But some things are known.  For example, Gerald Schwarz has studied the case of $G_2$.  To see what I outlined above played out in detail for $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ see page 11 of my paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.4403.pdf.

Comment: @ Sean Lawton, thanks once again

Answer (score 4):

The orthogonal and symplectic  case are treated in my old paper as well, there is a paper by Gerry Schwarz  on G_2,  always in characteristic 0, the theory in positive characteristic is presented  in
The Invariant Theory of Matrices  – 30 dicembre 2017
di Corrado De Concini (Autore), Claudio Procesi (Autore)

the case of 2\times 2  matrices is very special and can be described in full detail  see

Rings With Polynomial Identities and Finite Dimensional Representations of Algebras  – 30 dicembre 2020
Eli Aljadeff (Autore), Antonio Giambruno (Autore), Claudio Procesi (Autore), Amitai Regev (Autore)

Comment: Many thanks! Prof Procesi